# How to restore the last value of a field by code?

Tags: delphi, dataset, delphi-2007

In the `TField.OnValidate` event hanlder, I have to ask the user to confirm the new typed value.
If he doesn't confirm, I want to restore back the last value.

Currently, I'm doing as in the following example:

```
procedure  TForm1.FldOnValidate(AField : TField);
begin
  if(MessageDlg('Are you sure?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrNo) then
  begin
    Abort;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Dst : TClientDataSet;
  Dsc : TDataSource;
  Fld : TStringField;
  Grid : TDBGrid;
begin
  //dataset
  Dst := TClientDataSet.Create(Self);
  Dst.FieldDefs.Add('TEST', ftString, 20);
  Dst.CreateDataSet();
  Dst.Active := True;
  Fld := Dst.Fields[0] as TStringField;
  Dst.Append();
  Fld.AsString := 'a';
  Dst.Post();
  Fld.OnValidate := FldOnValidate;

  //datasource
  Dsc := TDataSource.Create(Self);
  Dsc.DataSet := Dst;

  //grid
  Grid := TDBGrid.Create(Self);
  Grid.DataSource := Dsc;
  Grid.Columns.Add.FieldName := Fld.FieldName;
  Grid.Align := alClient;
  Grid.Parent := Self;
end;
```

**Test steps:**

1. Run application
2. Type 'b'
3. Press the 'Enter' key
4. Press the 'Yes' button
5. Type 'c'
6. Press the 'Enter' key
7. Press the 'No' button
8. Press the 'Esc' key

The value `'b'` will be restored.

I want to avoid the point 8, when the user press the `'No'` button, I would like to automatically reset the previous value.

**Attempt:**

I've tried as follows but the `OldValue` is `'c'` (And I don't think it's the right way to do what I need).

```
procedure  TForm1.FldOnValidate(AField : TField);
begin
  if(MessageDlg('Are you sure?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrNo) then
  begin
    AField.OnValidate := nil;
    try
      AField.AsVariant := AField.OldValue;
    finally
      AField.OnValidate := FldOnValidate;
    end;
    Abort;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `TField.DataSet.Cancel` as

```
procedure  TForm1.FldOnValidate(AField : TField);
begin
  if MessageDlg('Are you sure?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrNo then
      Sender.DataSet.Cancel;
end;
```

- If the Yes button clicked the OnValidate event handler does not raise an exception, the data is written to the current record buffer and then the OnChange event handler is called.
- If the No button clicked then the **[`Cancel`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Cancel)** procedure will called and all modifications to the active record if those changes are not yet posted will be canceled.

Why?

From **[`docs`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TField.OnValidate)**

> To reject the current value of the field from the OnValidate event handler, raise an exception.

So, since you don't want to raise an exception, this is the only way to do so.

The **OnValidate** event handler is for validating the data, not for confirmation.

This will be easy if you are using newest versions of Delphi, cause it provides

- **[`FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.SavePoint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.SavePoint)**.
- **[`Caching Updates (FireDAC)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Caching_Updates_(FireDAC))**.

---

*UPDATE:*

```
  if MessageDlg('Validate?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrNo then
    Sender.DataSet.Cancel
      else
        Sender.DataSet.Post;
```

Steps:

- Type `'b'` and click `Yes`
- Type `'c'` and click `No`
- The value will return to `'b'` just as you want

> *Tested with Delphi 10 seattle using a TFDMemTable*.

Comment: Sure that this will work? I'd have guessed that this won't work as the DataSet has already been posted.

Comment: @nil Yes, if you click _No_ then the oldValue will remain. If you click _Yes_ the data will change. and the **OnValidate** fires before **OnChange**, so the data won't be posted

Comment: upvoted, but the field's value goes back to 'a' instead of 'b'

Comment: @Fabrizio Yes, cause the changes is not posted

Comment: Ok but when I press the 'Esc' key, it's able to retrieve back from somewhere the 'b' value. Isn't there a way to do the same at the dataset's level?

Comment: I can't post/cancel all changes in the record each time. I think this approach doesn't fit to my scenario :(. The only behavior I need is the one obtained by pressing the 'Esc' key